# Appengine: ClassCastException in query with string of leng

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

In my Google App Engine project I got an unexpected exception:

com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String org.learnjapanese.client.NewAccount.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key

```
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:378)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:581)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
```

This is my JPA-code:

```
@Entity
public class Test {
 @Id
 String id;
}
```

And this is the application code:

```
EntityManager manager = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

Query q = manager.createQuery("select x from Test x where id = '12'");
List l = q.getResultList(); // No problem here

q = manager.createQuery("select x from Test x where id = '1'");
l = q.getResultList(); // java.lang.ClassCastException occurs here.
```

It turns out that a query with a String of length 1 causes the exception, while the String with length 2 does not. Can anyone explain what is going on here? Is there a workaround?

Comment: what happens when you do this? `"select x from Test x where id = \"1\""`

Comment: That solves it, it doesn't trigger the exception. It's strange though, because the specification says that string literals are enclosed in single quotes (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_lit)

Comment: It may be a problem with the app engine: The problem in http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=21 is very similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java a single character enclosed in single quotes is interpreted as a char literal. It looks like this is what's happening when you use `'1'` in your statement. The stack trace is talking about an instance of `java.lang.Character` which is what you would get if a char was auto-boxed. Sounds like a bug in the framework you're using.